# Semiconductors: why the mass action law is not valid for very low temperatures?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, temperature, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

I thought that it was valid for very low temperatures since for it to be valid I think that it is necessary to be in the non-degeneracy condition, which requires $E_G >> k_B T$ (with $E_G$ being the energy gap), that it is satisfied at very low temperatures... But maybe at too low temperatures the non-degeneracy condition breaks for some other reason. And the Ashcroft and Mermin's book only helps to increase my confusion! Could someone help me figuring it out, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The law of mass actions says that in steady-state or equilibrium the product for electron concentration $n$ and hole concentration $p$ is a constant at all locations in a semiconductor,

$$np=n_i^2$$

It's true that the intrinsic carrier concentration $n_i$ is a function of temperature but the law does not break down as this would break charge neutrally.

Probably what you mean is that if you replace the Fermi-Dirac distribution with the Boltzmann distribution you can write,

$$
n_i^2= N_cN_ve^{(E_g/(kT))}
$$

The question is, is this expression valid at low termperture?

If you have a source with more background that would be helpful.